# Swift decode JSON array of object based on property value type

Tags: json, swift, codable, decodable

How to decode an array of different JSON objects, where the same property on each object tells you what type to use to decode it:

```
let json =
"""
[
    {
        "@type": "FirstObject",
        "number": 1
    },
    {
        "@type": "SecondObject",
        "name": "myName"
    }
]
"""
```

Here is some code [based on this similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57785601/codable-decode-property-with-multiple-object-types-based-on-another-value) which gets most of the way there, but fails because it doesn't know what CodingKeys are for `.data`:

```
struct FirstObject: MyData {
    var dataType: String
    var number: Int
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case dataType = "@type"
        case number
    }
}

struct SecondObject: MyData {
    var dataType: String
    var name: String
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case dataType = "@type"
        case name
    }
}

struct SchemaObj: Decodable
{
    var dataType: String
    var data: MyData
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case data
        case dataType = "@type"
    }
                
    enum ParseError: Error {
        case UnknownSchemaType(Any)
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        dataType = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .dataType)
        switch dataType {
        case "FirstObject":
            data = try container.decode(FirstObject.self, forKey: .data)
        case "SecondObject":
            data = try container.decode(SecondObject.self, forKey: .data)
        default:
            throw ParseError.UnknownSchemaType(dataType)
        }
    }
}

do {
    let data = Data(json.utf8)
    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode([SchemaObj].self, from: data)
    print(result)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Printed error is
`keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "data", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"data\", intValue: nil) (\"data\").", underlyingError: nil))`

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need the `data` coding key, since there's no "data" JSON key. Just decode the `data` property from the same decoder, based on the value of the JSON field:

```swift
struct SchemaObj: Decodable
{

    var dataType: String
    var data: MyData

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        dataType = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .dataType)

        switch dataType {
        case "FirstObject":
            data = try FirstObject(from: decoder)
        case "SecondObject":
            data = try SecondObject(from: decoder)
        default:
            throw ParseError.UnknownSchemaType(dataType)
        }
    }

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case dataType = "@type"
    }
}
```

If you plan to add more types to that list, then the `if/else if` can can become hard to manage, to improve the situation you can use a lookup table to address this:

```
static let typeMapping: [String: MyData.Type] = [ "FirstObject": FirstObject.self ,
                                                  "SecondObject": SecondObject.self]

init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    let dataType = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .dataType)
    
    guard let classToDecode = Self.typeMapping[dataType] else {
        throw ParseError.UnknownSchemaType(dataType)
    }
    
    self.dataType = dataType
    self.data = try classToDecode.init(from: decoder)
}
```